# Values in the while loop do not modify outside values

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a long code but I tried to copy and adapt my problem in as few lines as possible . I have a method which creates an array( 2D ) with 0 and 1

```
array1 = newValue(2)  - the number 2 represents how many 1 the array has
array2 = newValue(3)
```

and this loop

```
(0..9).each do|i|
(0..9).each do|j|
    while((array1[i][j] == array2[i][j]) && (array2[i][j] == 1))  do
      array1 = newvalue(2)
      array2 = newvalue(3)
  end
 end
end
```

I'm using the while loop so I won t have a 1 in the same position in both arrays . But what is inside the while loop doesn't modify the values of the array . I also tried using map!/collect! but I think I did something wrong because nothing happened. I hope you can understand what I was trying to do .

Edit:

```
def newValue(value)
value = value.to_i
array = Array.new(10)  { Array.new(10 , 0) }
(a lot of conditions on how to position the items in the array)
return array
end
```

Comment: what is the `newvalue` method doing?  This is just trying to fill a 2d array?  A little more context might help us help you.  It feels like you probably want that inner thing to look more like `array1[i][j] = newvalue(2)` or something, but since i'm not sure what you're trying to do, it's hard to know.

Comment: Do you mean to have it do `array1[i] = newValue(2)` and `array2[i] = newValue(3)` ?  The problem is probably because you're trying to assign a 1d array (the return from newValue) to a 2d array (array1 and array2).  Also, in your while statement `array2` will never equal `1` if it is in fact a 2d array - again, you're mixing apples and oranges, so to speak.

Comment: @mrrogers my while loops is supposed to find if array1 and array2 have an item with the value of 1 position at exactly the same coordinates . If they do they will be assigned new values. (I modified the condition now, I missed that when I wrote the program here . )

Comment: This method is creating a 2d array with all the items set to 0 array = Array.new(10)  { Array.new(10 , 0) }

Comment: Then I'll stick with the while loop issue.  I think you need `array2[i][j] == 1` as the last part of that while loop clause.  The rest might actually work.

Comment: I do have that. And it doesn't work. I need another method in the while loop to modify the array . After the while loop the array still has the first value

Comment: it gets more complicated... ;)

Comment: Can you post the entire `newValue` method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take... hopefully it'll help out.  It seems that what you noticed was true.  The arrays are not getting reset.  Probably because inside the each blocks, the scope is lost.  This is probably because the are arrays.  I took a slightly different approach.  Put everything in a class so you can have instance variables that you can control and you know where they are and that they are always the same.

I pulled out the `compare_arrays` function which just returns the coordinates of the match if there is one.  If not it returns `nil`.  Then, youre while loop is simplified in the `reprocess` method.  If you found a match, reprocess until you don't have a match any more.  I used a dummy `newValue` method that just returned another 2d array (as you suggested yours does).  This seems to do the trick from what I can tell.  Give it a whirl and see what you think.  You can access the two arrays after all the processing with `processor.array1` as you can see I did at the bottom.

```
# generate a random 2d array with 0's and val's
def generateRandomArray(val=1)
  array = []
  (0..9).each do |i|
    (0..9).each do |j|
      array[i] ||= []
      array[i][j] = (rand > 0.1) ? 0 : val
    end
  end 
  array
end

array1 = generateRandomArray
array2 = generateRandomArray

def newValue(val)
  generateRandomArray(val)
end

class Processor
  attr_reader :array1, :array2

  def initialize(array1, array2)
    @array1 = array1
    @array2 = array2
  end

  def compare_arrays
    found = false
    for ii in 0..9
      break unless for jj in 0..9
                     if ((@array2[ii][jj] == 1) && (@array1[ii][jj] == 1)) 
                       found = true
                       break
                     end
                   end
    end
    [ii,jj] if found
  end

  def reprocess
    while compare_arrays
      puts "Reprocessing"
      @array1 = newValue(2)
      @array2 = newValue(3)
      reprocess
    end
  end
end


processor = Processor.new(array1, array2)
processor.reprocess

puts processor.array1.inspect
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing happens .. I think you used a different method to assign values to the arrays, because I can t use this part in mine processor = Processor.new(array1, array2)

Comment: I updated the post to include my versions of the 2d array generation which is also used for my fake `newValue` method.  Is there any way to post the newValue method with a bit more detail?  Maybe the problem is inside there?

Comment: I found another way :d . I had too many arrays for that method to handle